# Jersey and Object Mapper

Tags: java, jersey, objectmapper

I am a bit confused as to when I need to use an object mapper. I thought it should be used for mapping a result set from a DB query into objects so I created an object mapper like this:

```
public class PersonMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Person>
{
    public Person map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setPersonId(resultSet.getShort("PersonId"));
        person.setPersonType((PersonType) resultSet.getObject("PersonType"));
        person.setPersonName(resultSet.getString("PersonName"));
        person.setPersonMobile(resultSet.getString("PersonMobile"));
        return person;
    }
}
```

Then I registered it with the specific DAO like this: `@RegisterMapper(PersonMapper.class)`

However, it seems that everything also works without the mapper even if I make a query like this: `List<Person> list = list(namedQuery("Person.findAll"));` which returns a proper list.

So when exactly should I use a mapper?

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about ObjectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) class then we use it to save an entire POJO object as JSON string into the database, in which you need to keep the data type of the column as json while table creation...

so we use it like this

```
public Response saveStateRules(@Context HttpServletRequest request,StatePojo statePojo)
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(statePojo);

        State state = new State();

        state.setRulejson(json);
}
```

where,

```
public class StatePojo implements Serializable{

    private Integer stateid;
    private ArrayList<StateRuleCondition> fieldconditions;
    private ArrayList<Integer> stateids;

    private Boolean isallow;

// contains all getters and setters

}
```

Comment: the result setmapper is defined in org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.ResultSetMapper

Comment: btw what does Jersey use as default to handling Json? I did not define something specific

Comment: May i know where you want to handle json? i mean any condition where handling is required

Comment: For example the user may send me a json string to the web service and Jersey is creating for me an object automatically without a mapper (The method of the webservice receives that object as a parameter).. how does it do it?

Comment: that is what i have done in the posted example.. i am getting a json String in StatePojo object which is been created by jquery/ javascript, using "JSON.stringify({stateid: "5" , isallow :true})" method, so this entire StatePojo i can save in database if database contains column data type as json

Comment: You used it to convert the object to a json string and I don't understand why would you do that.. Anyway this is probably not the same mapper since mine is creating an object, not a json string.

Comment: actually we save  entire json string into our DB as that json string we use in our android app , and retrieve it whenever required at back end, by converting back to reuired class object via ObjectMapper..                               where ,     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                                                                 someClass classObj = mapper.readValue(pojo.getjson(), someClass.class);     this way we retrieve the saved json string from database